# Laravel BelongsToMany table relation

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

I have an issue i can't resolve myself with the documentation.

I want to create a very simple conversation system between two users.

I have 3 models and tables:

**User**
id , name

**Conversation**
id

**Message**
id , user_id , conversation_id , content

So a message belongsTo an user and a conversation but then i want the conversation to belongstomany users.

And i dont know how to make this with the tables. If i create a `user_id` fields in the conversation table i can't have multiple users...

Answer (score 0):

[This is definitely in the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#many-to-many)

Anyways. You're looking for a many to many relationship. For that you need a pivot table (or junction table) that contains the id of a user and the id of a conversation.

Following Laravel convention this table would be called `conversation_user` and would have the columns `id` (primary key), `conversation_id` and `user_id`

If you have that you can define the relations like this:

#### User

```
public function conversations(){
   return $this->belongsToMany('Conversation');
}
```

#### Conversation

```
public function users(){
   return $this->belongsToMany('User');
}
```

#### Querying the relation

```
$user = User::find(1);
$conversations = $user->conversations;
```

---

As documented [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#inserting-related-models) for inserting models into a many to many relation you should use `attach()`

```
$conversation = new Conversation;
$conversation->users()->attach($idUser1);
$conversation->users()->attach($idUser2);

// or just pass an array of ids

$conversation->users()->attach(array($idUser1, $idUser2));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first of all have the three folowig tables:

**User**

id , name

**Conversation_user**

user_id , message_id

**Message**

id , content

Than let's take care of the relationships.

In your User model:

```
public function conversations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Message::class,'conversation_user','user_id','message_id');
}
```

In your Message model:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'conversation_user','message_id','user_id');
}
```

Now you will be able to call the relationship like so:

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user->conversations();
```